# How to get first date and last date of all twelve months for given year in Oracle PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

If i give input year like '**2021**' i need result as below

```
Month   Start Date  End Date

1   1/1/2021    31/01/2021
2   1/2/2021    28/01/2021
.       
.       
.       
.       
.       
.       
.       
.       
.       
12  1/12/2021   31/12/2021
```

Comment: Please, show what did you try so far and what was wrong with it. Do you have a problems with generation of 12 months of the year? Do you have problems to identify first or last day?

Comment: If any of the answers solved or helped solve your issue then please accept that answer. See the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). This helps later questioners that have the same issue, and cleans up the open question queue. If none have solved your issue, then what is it not resolved.

Comment: Yes , i got the result

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it is about the *row generator* technique; there are plenty of them, pick any you want. (Have a look at [OraFAQ](https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques)).

For example:

```
SQL> with mon as
  2    (select add_months(trunc(to_date(&par_year, 'yyyy'), 'yyyy'), level - 1) val
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= 12
  5    )
  6  select to_char(val, 'mm') mon,
  7         val start_date,
  8         last_day(val) end_date
  9  from mon
 10  order by 1;
Enter value for par_year: 2021

MO START_DATE END_DATE
-- ---------- ----------
01 01/01/2021 31/01/2021
02 01/02/2021 28/02/2021
03 01/03/2021 31/03/2021
04 01/04/2021 30/04/2021
05 01/05/2021 31/05/2021
06 01/06/2021 30/06/2021
07 01/07/2021 31/07/2021
08 01/08/2021 31/08/2021
09 01/09/2021 30/09/2021
10 01/10/2021 31/10/2021
11 01/11/2021 30/11/2021
12 01/12/2021 31/12/2021

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use directly the model clause for that purpose.

```sql
SELECT n 
    ,  TO_DATE(&the_year||lpad(f, 2, '0'), 'YYYYMM') start_dt
    ,  last_day(TO_DATE(&the_year||lpad(f, 2, '0'), 'YYYYMM')) end_dt
FROM DUAL
MODEL
    DIMENSION by (1 as n)
    MEASURES (1 as f)
    RULES (
        f[FOR n FROM 1 TO 12 INCREMENT 1 ] = cv(n)
    )
;
```

The advantage of the model clause is if you later want to get the every other month, you just need to change the increment from 1 to 2. Or if you are looking for the quarter months of the year (January, April, Jully, October), you just need to change increment from 1 to 3, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Just replace 2021 in the query for your year

```
with months (m) as (
  select 1 from dual union all
  select m + 1 from months where m < 12
)
select 
  to_date('2021' || '-' || to_char(m) || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as first_day,
  last_day(to_date('2021' || '-' || to_char(m) || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) as last_day
from months
```

You can try on this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8889cc9b0245c6cd391b4a92c3be793d)

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
WITH cte_date as(
    SELECT 
    LEVEL Month_No,
    to_date(to_char(LEVEL||'-2021'),'MM-YYYY') Start_Date FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <=12
)
SELECT Month_No, Start_Date, LAST_DAY(Start_Date) End_Date
FROM cte_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of recursive CTEs because they are part of Standard SQL.  I would phrase this as:

```
with months (month, startdate) as (
     select 1 as month, date '2021-01-01'
     from dual
     union all
     select month + 1, add_months(startdate, 1)
     from months
     where month < 12
    )
select month, startdate, last_day(startdate) as enddate
from months;
```

If you need an input year, there are different ways to accomplish it.  But a simple way is to change the second line to:

```
 select 1 as month, to_date(:year || '0101', 'YYYYMMDD')
```